Help/ideas on how to evaluate this integral?
I have the following integral
$$\int_0^{t_f}\frac{\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \right)^2}{x^4(t)}dt. $$
I can reduce this using
$$\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}dt = \frac{dx}{dt}dx \to \int_{\infty}^{x_{f}}\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{x^4}dx.$$
The limits of integration arise because the integral represents a physical situation: two massive particles start infinitely far apart and approach each other up to a certain point $x_f$. I'm not sure how to proceed. For example, I thought about separation of variables, $u=dx/dt$ and $dv=dx/x^4$, but this (I think) yields an integral of the form
$$-\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{d(\dot{x})}{x^3} .$$
If $\dot{x}$ and $x$ are treated as independent variables, this integral reduces to the same term that appears when separating variables (the $uv$ term). The end result appears to be $0$.
Any ideas?
EDIT: For more context, the integral appears in the context of calculating the energy irradiated by gravitational waves, from two distant point masses that follow universal gravitation, $\ddot{x}=\frac{-GM}{x^2}$, $x$ being the separation between masses. One has to calculate the reduced quadrupole moment
$$\bar{I}_{ij}=I_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}\mathrm{tr}(I_{ij}) \ \mathrm{where} \ I_{ij}=\int T^{00}x_i x_j d^3x.$$
Where $T^{00}$ is the energy density of the system. I haved calculate this to have 3 non-zero terms: $\bar{I}_{xx}=\frac{2}{3}\mu x^2, \bar{I}_{yy}=\bar{I}_{zz}=\frac{-1}{3}\mu x^2$ ($\mu$ is the reduced mass of the system, a parameter). From here, the energy lost per unit time is
$$L=\frac{G}{5c^5}\frac{d^3\bar{I}_{ij}}{dt^3}\frac{d^3\bar{I}^{ij}}{dt^3}. $$
And then the energy is the integral of this with respect to time. Ignoring constants, I have calculated it to be the integral at the start of the post.

What makes you think there is some nice closed form of this?

It's an exercise question that's supposed to reduce into some relatively simple solution, to then compare with an approximate result.

Could you include the full exercise question?

Here you go. Maybe I have miscalculated something, but I don't think I have. For even more context, the $T^{00}$ term is basically just the mass of the particles times delta functions for their positions as they are point-like.

Solved. On physical grounds, the following relationship holds:
$$\frac{1}{2}\mu (\dot{x})^2 = \frac{GM\mu}{x} $$
Solve for $\dot{x}$ and substitute. The rest is trivial calculus.
